# Listing active machines in network?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, vmware-vcenter

I recently needed to patch almost 100 linux virtual machines on a subnet. To get a list of machines on the network I used `nmap` to retrieve all IP addresses in this network. The issue is that some of these machines were terminated or turned off permanently, but nmap cannot detect this and it was a lot of wasted time.

```
nmap -sn <ip>/24 | grep Nmap
```

Is there a better way to get a list of IP addresses that only retrieves **active** machines? All these machines are connected to a VMWare cluster and have VMWare agents running, if there's a way I can use this?

*linux only, not windows*

Comment: And now you start realizing why large companies deploy softawre to manage servers that installs agents on the servers and connects to a management server ;)

Comment: @TomTom we do actually use puppet quite well, but in this particular instance there was no orchestration to help :)

Comment: please post the nmap command used, there are lots of switches to detect different states of target machines.

Comment: @rob see my edit

Comment: odd, ` -sn` should require the target machine to be running an ICMP service to be able to return a positive. For Linux machine I normally target ssh port `nmap -sS -p 22 <ip>/24`

Comment: @rob Ah - some of the IP's returned were from the same machine with 2 interfaces, some IPs were gateway IPs, and some just had dead machines that were no longer active

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with powershell.

This fetches all VMs that are connected to a given network and are powered on:

```powershell
Get-VirtualPortGroup -Name $networkname |Get-VM |Where-Object { $_.PowerState -eq 'PoweredOn'}
```

You can filter for more attributes (for example VMware Tools running or not).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how can I achieve this in linux?

Comment: I just ran this command in linux to test it before copying it here. Install powershell, install PowerCLI.

Comment: oh, ill give this a go! thanks.